# 11ty multiple data sources for one template

Tags: nunjucks, eleventy

I'm using 11ty to build static web pages.
I am creating data sources as json files and storing them in the globally accessible _data directory.

```
template.njk
```

```
{% for key, value in data %}
    <div>
        <span class="text-4xl">{{key}}</span>

        <ul>
           {% for item in value %}
            <li>{{ item.country }}</li>
           {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

```
_data
    data_source_1.json
    data_source_2.json
    data_source_3.json
```

I don't want to have 3 templates. I just want one template.
How do I pass each data source as a variable to the template?

Comment: ok, I'm starting to think this is not possible in this system. If I don't get an answer soon I will post my work around as a solution ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

11ty is different from the JavaScript frameworks/libraries around. You don't need to "bring in" all your data on each template if multiple sources. It can be done trough Collections or global _data files in the "create once, use anywhere" style.

Check that short EggHead video about creating pages (and the collection) from _data pages: https://egghead.io/lessons/11ty-generate-eleventy-11ty-pages-from-external-data

Its like the basic example from the docs with the possums array, but the `addAllPagesToCollections: true` line in the front matter will create the globally usable collection.

Say you add another template to display a single element from _data source and add all to collections, in a books.njk template... Then on any page without "bringing in data in the front matter" you can:

```
{% for book in collections.books %}
  ## [ {{ book.data.title }} ]( {{ book.url }} )
{% endfor %}
```

...that way you can have as much different "data sources" collections on a single page. There are for sure more to say on the subject but hope it helped and pointed you in the direction to digg in the docs & online in general.

Edit:

Depending on your data and if no individual pages are needed, you can also store your global _data pages directly in .json and loop trough them without creating a collection.

*_data/family.json*

```
{
  "possums":[
    {
        "name": "Fluffy",
        "age": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Sparky",
        "age": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "Boby",
        "age": 1
      }
  ]
}
```

*someTemplate.md*

```
{% for possum in family.possums %}
  {{ possum.name }} is {{possum.age}} years old
{% endfor %}
```

Storing _data files as .js is also possible by exporting, but the simplest way for small bits of data can be the.json way.

Most of time you'll have a `_data/website.json` file, with global data like "name, tagline, whatever".

Comment: thank you for your reply. So, to be clear you use the pagination feature in front matter where you can give the location of the data file? I had tried that before and felt like it was a hack, but if that's the way to do it I will press on.....

Comment: thank you for your help. I'm accepting your answer because I think it shows the 11ty way. Although in my case using collections through pagination doesn't seem to solve the problem. Your other suggestion of using a named data source is what I will use but I wish it could be passed as a variable

Comment: Glad it helped. You could look into "Shortcodes" from the docs. It's done in JavaScript so you can import your data and tweak around to fit your needs then use it in templates. One way of another ...happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

So, on the basis it cant be done in this manner:
My work around is to make a dedicated template for each data set. Seems to defeat the object of having a template. Anyway, I am building the data and templates from a bespoke php and mysql backend.